# python code blocks in org-mode don't have persistent sessions in emacs24.3

Tags: python, emacs, org-mode, emacs24

Has something significant changed in how org-mode handles the `:session` argument in source code blocks between Emacs24.1 and Emacs24.3? I cannot get a persistent python session running anymore, and I used to be able to. For example, something like this used to work in Emacs24.1

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :session sample
x = 12;
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output :session sample
print "x =", x
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: x = 12
```

But in Emacs24.3 the second block would throw an error saying the `x` is undefined. Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 3):

This is apparently a known problem among the `org-mode` developers. It seems to have arisen only very recently. It is not yet known what caused it to suddenly break.

One could expect the fix to be included in the current beta version of `org-mode`: the to-be version 8.0.